# Updating Bookmarks in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 bookmarks on the same page in Power BI.

I make my changes and then update the bookmark, but then it also updates the other bookmark on this page.

Both bookmarks are for the selected visual only.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, refreshing would lead to changes in both the bookmarks as they are linked to the same page/visual. You could try creating two separate similar tiles and hide one in each bookmark. This might generate the output you wish for.